# i need to get more than one value from database sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, select

I need to get 6 values from database and bind them to link button texts her is the code

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string post = Request.QueryString["post"];
        ////string title = "nokia";

        string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(); 

        conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\nokiaoaq\Desktop\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            //string str = "insert into Table1 (title , date_ ,www, cat) values  (' " + TextBox1.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "')";
            ////string str = "INSERT INTO Table1  (title,date_,www ) values ('ddddddd','aaaaaaa','qqqqqq')";


            string str =
                //"SELECT   from table1  WHERE  cat = 1 and datee='" + date + "'ORDER BY datee";
            "SELECT table1.title  FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and datee='" + date + "'ORDER BY datee DESC";

            SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da1.Fill(dt);

            //DataRow dr = new DataRow();
            //DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ml1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                ml2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                ml3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                ml4.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                ml5.Text = dr[4].ToString();
                ml6.Text = dr[5].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label4.Text = "Failed to connect to data source";
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

ml is link button id

Comment: There's no question here. Does the code not work? What happens? Are there any errors?

Comment: **warning** your code promotes a bad pattern that may introduce sql injection attacks.

Comment: maybe there's only one record that has a Cat of 1 and the given datee

Comment: fixed the issue with a foreach loop and an integer thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign 6 fields from the row returned to 6 different textboxes, but your select query asks for just one field. If you want more than one field returned then add their names to the select query (change fieldX to the appropriate field name).

```
string str = "SELECT title, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5  " + 
             "FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and datee=@dt ORDER BY datee DESC";
```

also do not use string concatenation to build the sql statement. Use always a parametrized query

```
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", datee);
.....
```

this will avoid problem with formatting strings, date, numbers etc, but also the sql injection problem.

By the way, I hope that your code returns just one row because, as it stands now, if you have more than one row returned then only the one with the earliest date will be shown in the textboxes. (And if this is the case then the order by is useless).  If you have more than one row returned then you should consider to bind the datatable to a GridView to show all records returned.

Comment: but +1 nevertheless for promoting parameterised queries

Comment: that's is controlled by the where clause. but he read 6 fields from the rows and ask just for one